# Saber que un compañero a hecho push a un repositorio remoto en github

Tags: linux, git, github, git-commit, push

¿Hay algún comando git para saber si al repositorio remoto se han hecho push? Por que estoy trabajando con un compañero y cada vez que quiero subir un commit mio tengo que ir a la web de github y comprobar allí si se ha hecho un 'push'. Ya me ha pasado varias veces que quiero hacer push de mi repositorio local al remoto y encontrarme con el mensaje

> Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
> consejo: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
> consejo: to the same ref.

Luego en mi repositorio local tengo que eliminar mi commit hacer un pull al remoto y luego volver ha hacer mi commit. Hay alguna forma para saber que se ha hecho un push al remoto desde la consola git.

Gracias

Comment: Revisa [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git)

Comment: Hola @chikebox pensaba que habría una forma más sencilla. La opción más rápida que he visto es git ls-remote y te indica el último comit donde esta el HEAD.Luego hago git --log a mi local y lo comparo. Yo andaba buscando hacer un git log al remoto.

Comment: Pues he encontrado git log --remotes y parece que puede ser la respuesta

Comment: y teneis que hacerlo vía comandos?, quiero decir hay software digamos "visual" como SourceTree que te permite hacer todo esto de forma gráfica, te lo dejo como alternativa

Comment: No necesitas eliminar tu commit para volver a añadirlo después de pull. Puedes hacer `git pull --rebase` que hace exactamente lo mismo

Comment: Buenas tardes abulafia mire el comando git pull --rebase  y es como dices, gracias. Voy a cerrar la pregunta